# ODE describing a population of $N$ individuals where individuals are either type $A$ or $B$ but not both

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, stability-in-odes, fixed-points

I'm currently going through Computational Methods course notes and came across this:

> Consider a population of $N$ individuals where individuals are either
> of type $A$ or $B$ but not both. At any point in time, an individual
> can only be be of one type. All individuals can be assumed to be in
> contact with all other individuals. At time $t=0$, there are $b(0)$
> type $B$ individuals and all other individuals are type $A$. Type $B$ individuals turn to type $A$ at a fixed rate $\gamma$. Type $A$
> individuals turn into type $B$ at a rate $\frac{\beta b}{N}$, i.e.,
> proportional to the number of their contacts that are type $B$.

I want to find the fixed points of this system along with their stability. To this end, I want to express $\dot{b}$ as a function of $b$ and equate it to 0 then solve for the corresponding values of $a$ and $b$. However I'm confused as my model (as I understand it) $$\dot{b}=\frac{\beta}{N}b - \gamma$$ differs from the model given by the notes $$\dot{b}=\beta\frac{b}{N}a - \gamma b.$$

I'm confused as it seems that the dimensions don't agree in the second differential equation, it seems to me that the LHS is $\frac{people}{time}$ but the RHS is $\frac{people^2}{time}$.

For this example, how does one find the fixed points of the system?

Comment: I don't see anything wrong in your model. If $\Delta b$ represents the change in the population of $B$ individuals on the small time interval $[t,t+\Delta t)$ then we would expect $\gamma \Delta t$ individuals to leave group $B$ and joint group $A$ while $\frac{\beta b}{N}\Delta t$ indidviduals to leave group $A$ and join group $B$. Hence $$\Delta b\approx -\gamma \Delta t + \frac{\beta b}{N}\Delta t$$ This implies $$\frac{db}{dt}=-\gamma+\frac{\beta b}{N}$$

Comment: How is the given model in the second equation correct?